# Find such an analytic isomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

The question is to find an analytic isomorphism from the open region between $x=1$ to $x=3$ to the upper half unit disk: $\{|z|<1, \text{Im}(z)>0\}$. I would know how to deal with this if it just asks to find an isomorphism from the $x>1$ to the full unit disk. In such a scenario where the region given is truncated, i.e not a full half plane or circle how do we go about approach this? Any hints would be appreciated!

I am thinking of finding an isomorphism such that it maps $x>1$ to the full unit circle $|z|<1$ and that it maps $x>3$ to the lower half circle. The restriction of this isomorphism to $1<x<3$ is the one we want. But how can I go about ensuring the latter condition is satisfied?

Comment: Hint: $\log{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ sends conformally the unit disc into a horizontal strip of width $\pi$ centered on the real axis, so the upper part of the disc is sent to the upper part of the strip; you just need to rotate by $90$ degrees (clockwise) to make it vertical (and the upper part goes to the right), scale so the half-width is $2$ rather than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and then translate by $1$ to send to where you want; then just invert it and you get your isomorphism

Comment: Yes I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome